# Reading Excel file: IndexError: single positional indexer out-of-bounds

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter data in an Excel file based on patient number, message type, and test level, and then calculate the average of the lists in each cell of the 'RPS' column. However, I keep encountering an error.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

# Verilerinizi içeren Excel dosyasını okuyun
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/bastu/busra_hoca/patient3-4/dot2.xlsx")

hasta_listesi = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
tip_listesi = ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]
test_levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, "n1", "n2"]

result = []

for hasta in hasta_listesi:
    for tip in tip_listesi:
        for test_level in test_levels:
            # Filtreleme işlemi
            filtre = (df['Patient'] == hasta) & (df['Message'] == tip) & (df['Test Levet'] == test_level)
            # filtre = (df['Hasta'] == hasta) & (df['Mesaj'] == tip) & (df['Test Level'] == test_level)
            filtrelenmis_veri = df[filtre]
            index_liste = filtrelenmis_veri.index.tolist()
            
            
            toplam = 0
            for i in list(range(len(index_liste))):
                
                toplam += filtrelenmis_veri["RPS"].iloc[index_liste[i]]
                          
            
            result.append({"Hasta": hasta,
                           "Elektrot": tip,
                           "Test Seviyesi": test_level,
                           "Toplam": toplam,
                           "İndex Len": len(index_liste)})
```

Comment: Pls post the error you are getting

Comment: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1589 in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: the debugging details must be in plain text in your question. not as an image, not as a comment.

Comment: I included a picture to make the data understandable. While collecting the error
filtered_data["RPS"].iloc[index_list[i]] gives at this point. When I call the cells one by one, the list in each cell appears in front of me, but it does not enter the summation process. Although it is in the form of lists in the cells in Excel, when I look at it as type(filtered_data["RPS"].iloc[index_liste[i]]), it says it is str.

Comment: Your error seems to stem from indices going out of bounds, likely due to invalid indices in the index_liste. For debugging, inspect the contents of index_liste and the DataFrame filtrelenmis_veri to verify if the indices and DataFrame are as expected. This will help you identify whether the indices are correct and if the DataFrame filtering is functioning as intended. you can try to control it   `print("Index Listesi:", index_liste, "\nFiltrelenmiş Veri:\n", filtrelenmis_veri)`

Comment: When I check it gives lists for each index value

Comment: I think the 'Toplam' code is giving an error.  I'm sharing a code in answer can you try it

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the Excel file containing your data
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/bastu/busra_hoca/patient3-4/dot2.xlsx")

hasta_listesi = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
tip_listesi = ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]
test_levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, "n1", "n2"]

    result = []
    
    for hasta in hasta_listesi:
        for tip in tip_listesi:
            for test_level in test_levels:
                # Filtering
                filter_condition = (df['Patient'] == hasta) & (df['Message'] == tip) & (df['Test Levet'] == test_level)
                filtered_data = df[filter_condition]
                
                # Calculate mean of 'RPS' column
                mean_rps = filtered_data["RPS"].mean()
                
                result.append({"Patient": hasta,
                               "Message": tip,
                               "Test Level": test_level,
                               "Mean RPS": mean_rps})
    
    # Create a DataFrame from the result list
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    print(result_df)
```